# checking in code to a detached head

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project that has a submodule which is a detached head(It is designed this way). Now I have to make some changes to a file in the detached head. Below is what I did.

While I am in the detached head path`( /user/project/base ((d4b9ede...))`

```
git add testFile.py
git commit -m "made some change in this file"
git checkout -b temp
git checkout master
git pull
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
git push
```

After this I can see the changes made in the remote server when I open my gitlab project. But when I clone the same project I dont seem to see the change made to that file. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodules are indeed "designed that way": the superproject lists commit IDs for everything in the subprojects, so checking out the superproject gets you each subproject with a detached HEAD at its specific commit ID.

This is why you do not see your change: your subproject has a new commit on its `master` branch, but your superproject *does not use that branch* (at least, not in any direct way).

What this means is that after you have made and committed, and have already pushed, some changes to some submodule(s), you must *also*, separately, move to your superproject and tell git that this separate thing—the superproject—should now refer to the new commit in the subproject, by its (new) commit ID.

This appears to have changed since the last time I did it (git 1.5/1.6) so the old method—`cd` to the superproject and carefully `git add` the submodule, being sure not to use a trailing slash in the path name even if autocomplete *really wants* to have that `/` in there—is no longer the only method (though no doubt it still works).  These days you can also use `git submodule update --remote`, with optional `--no-fetch` as well.  This does require that you have first pushed the submodule update (and uses branch settings recorded in the superproject, either its `.git/config` or its `.gitmodules`, defaulting to `master`—this is where the `master` branch, or some other branch, finally re-enters the picture).

Once you have updated the superproject so that it knows the new commit ID, you must then commit to the superproject and push that.

The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and [this blog posting](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407) both have additional information on submodules.  I personally still try to avoid submodules; their "sobmodules" nickname was quite appropriate in the git 1.6 days, and may well still be, based on that blog post (which was updated as recently as mid-Jan 2016).

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. Really appreciate it. I did `git submodule update --remote` and saw that it now points to the new commit ID. But how do I push this change? In the superproject when I do `git add` I get this `Nothing specified, nothing added.
Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?` . So what exactly should I add here?

Comment: Once the submodule commit ID is updated, it should show up in `git diff` output (either as submodule commit ID or, if you've set the more user friendly submodule diff option, show the submodule log lines) and you should be ready to push the superproject.  Again, I have not actually done any of this for years, so it may have changed somewhat.

Comment: Thanks again. I pushed the submodule and it works fine. Just wanted to be sure before doing a push.